# Trigger lambda from cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created an alarm that looks for tunnels and sends SNS topic when tunnels are down. Is there a way to trigger lambda as well? I don't see any options for that. It looks like I can only create an event to trigger lambda.

[image]

Comment: Why not trigger the Lambda from SNS?  [SNS Lambda As Subscriber](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html)

Comment: @kenlukas - Thanks I tried that and its working. But how can I test this? Like, trigger a test case where tunnels are in Down/Up state?

Comment: I don't have much experience with SNS, but I believe you can go into the topic and publish a message to it.  Otherwise taking the tunnel up and down would work.